# In real time when we will use AOT and JIT

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have gone through the definition AOT and JIT, but did not get, In real time under which circumstances we will use each of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIT is used for local development and
AOT is used for production purpose because the bundle size will be much smaller, secure, etc;

Answer (score 3):

JIT

> Just-in-Time (JIT) is a type of compilation that compiles your app in
>   the browser at runtime. JIT compilation is the default when you run
>   the ng build (build only) or ng serve (build and serve locally) CLI
>   commands.

AOT

> Ahead-of-Time (AOT) is a type of compilation that compiles your app at
>   build time

Benefit using AOT

1. Faster rendering: The browser downloads a pre-compiled version of
   the application. So it can render the application immediately
   without compiling the app.
2. Fewer asynchronous requests: It inlines
   external HTML templates and CSS style sheets within the application
   javascript which eliminates separate ajax requests.
3. Smaller Angular
   framework download size: Doesn't require downloading the Angular
   compiler. Hence it dramatically reduces the application payload.
4. Detect template errors earlier: Detects and reports template binding
   errors during the build step itself
5. Better security: It compiles
   HTML templates and components into JavaScript. So there won't be any
   injection attacks.